# Github exclude specific user or files from mandatory pull requests

Tags: github, continuous-integration, pull-request

I need to push a file from my Jenkins CI server on build, the branch require pull requests,
is there a way to exclude a certain user or file from mandatory pull requests? 
thanks

Comment: If you are an Administrator of the repository and admins themselves are not restricted, you can directly push without creating a pull request.

Comment: Thanks Dibakar but I want to restrict admins, since some of the developers are admins.